# JQuery slideDown not working; both HTML elements displayed, slider effect not happening

Tags: jquery

My JQuery is not working and I cannot figure out why. I wonder if it has to do with recently upgrading to Windows 10, but I don't know. Here is my entire HTML page. Note: Even if I take out all links and scripts and just leave in the one for JQuery, it still doesn't work.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" class="container">
    <head>
    <title>Practice Search Results webpage</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script>
/* Jquery Slider Practice*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#AtomicNumbers").click(function(){
        $("#details").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
</script>
<style>
#AtomicNumbers, #details {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: pink;
        border: solid 1px black;
        width: 500px;
}   


</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>We found results near you!</h2>

<h3 id="AtomicNumbers"> Atomic Numbers</h3>
<p id="details">Here are the details about Atomic Numbers</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define "not working". What is or isn't happening?

Comment: This question will probaly get closed for low quality...check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to ask questions on Stackoverflow

Comment: Not working here means not doing anything. I'll be happy to change the title, but it seemed self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand what slidedown() does. Your `p` tag is already displayed in the html. So it will not do anything with slidedown(). If you want to see the effect, do this:

```
 $("#details").hide().slideDown("slow");
```

Comment: This helped a little bit. My page continued to display the <p> element, but if I clicked on the <h3>, I got a slideDown effect. Got anymore ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the following code. Thanks everyone.

```
#details {
     display: none;
}
```

I did not realize "display: none;" was needed.